# SIM808 Constantly send unwanted message

Tags: sim900

I have set the baud rate of [sim808](http://shop.aftabrayaneh.com/Sim808_GPS_GSM_Gprs_Bluetooth_Module_BK_Sim808__AFTAB.html?search=sim808) module to 57600 and with a [USB2TTL](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CP2102-USB-to-TTL-UART-to-232-485-Mutual-Convert-Module-DTR-RTS-3-3-5V-6-in-One-/301199835689) module connect it to my PC. Everything works fine and the module recognize the AT-Command except that constantly send the following message to the terminal

```
RDY
+CFUN: 1
+CPIN: READY
Call   Ready
sms    Ready
```

I wonder to know how can I stop sending these messages,
Is it possible that the module reset itself?

PS: Power indicator light is on and GSM Net light indicator is blinking.
PWRIN Voltage is 5V

Comment: What are you using as a power source, and what is regulating it down from 5v?  It's actually quite challenge to devise a non-battery source that can stand up to the peak pulse power needs of GSM, *especially* in its older forms as many of the UART interface modules implement.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply I use laboratory power supply that is capable of 5A

Comment: But what regulates it down to the ~4 volts the SIM808 actually requires?   And what sort of wiring have you used?  Depending on the regulator used and it's dropout (especially when sourcing what is likely out-of-spec current) your input voltage may actually be too low.

Comment: As in the Link says "Note: PWRIN range is from 5.0V to 10V, 5.0V is recommended," so I gave that pin Exactly 5V. the module has internal regulator

Comment: But what is the internal regulator?  You can't assume that the person who designed this knew what they were doing.

Comment: Based on the datasheet there is the two testing point one of them should have 2.8v and another 3.3V and both of them are correct.

Comment: That would only be meaningful if measured under load with a storage scope setup to trigger on a dip.  Also those are perhaps not the important voltages.  The transmitter itself will run off something like 4.2v - they're really designed for direct usage with a lithium cell.

Comment: Finally I have found out the module has MIC29302BU IC as voltage regulator